# Magento 2: Get category description

Tags: php, magento2

I am trying to load a collection of (sub) categories and display their description.

I tried the following things (without success). Used a collection with filter to get the root category. With this method only the root category gives back the correct description.

```
$cats = $this->categoryFactory
    ->create()
    ->setStoreId(1)
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('url_key',$this->getData( 'root_category_id' ))
    ->addAttributeToSelect(['description', 'url_key', 'name', 'store_id']);

var_dump($cats->getFirstItem()->getDescription()); // THIS WORKS!

// iterate subcats
foreach($cats->getFirstItem()->getChildrenCategories() as $subCat) {
    var_dump($subCat->getDescription()); // NULL
}
```

I am looking to get a category collection and filter by `parent_id` as I think this might work. However I don't get it to work. I have tried the following methods:

```
$cats = $this->categoryFactory
    ->create()
    ->setStoreId(1)
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id',$this->getCategory()->getId())
    ->addAttributeToSelect(['description', 'url_key', 'name', 'store_id']);
```

And:

```
$cats = $this->categoryFactory
    ->create()
    ->setStoreId(1)
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect(['description', 'url_key', 'name', 'store_id']);
    ->getSelect()->where ("catalog_category_entity.parent_id = " . $this->getCategory()->getId());
```

When I try to use the collection, PHP throws this error. I suspect that happens because it wants to load too much categories?

> Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of
>   792723456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 400572416 bytes)

I hope someone can steer me in the right direction.

Comment: I know I shouldn't be concatenating variables into SQL queries. So please don't mention, I'm doing this only for debugging-sake.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet I wrote from an old project, apologies I haven't tested it for you specifically but I do know that is still live on a production site today.

`$this->_categoryRepository` is an instance of `Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository`

```
/**
 * Get child categories of parent category id.
 * @param int $parentId
 * @return array
 */
public function getChildren(int $parentId): array
{
    $parent = $this->_categoryRepository->get($parentId);
    $childIds = explode(',', $parent->getChildren(false, true, true));

    $children = [];

    if (empty($childIds)) {
        return $children;
    }

    foreach ($childIds as $i => $id) {
        $children[] = $this->_categoryRepository->get($id);
    }

    return $children;
}
```

You'll notice I'm using the category repository rather than factory & collection. [This stack overflow question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/158081/when-should-we-use-a-repository-and-factory-in-magento-2) has some more in-depth info on that.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try it today and mark your answer as correct.

Comment: It's still giving me the "PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 3223322624) (tried to allocate 3219132416 bytes)" exception. Even when I used `ini_set('memory_limit', -1)`. It's happening with the first call to `$this->categoryRepository->get($id);` when looping through the child ids. I suspect there is some kind of infinite loop going on.

Comment: it could be because you have too many `childIds`, so that when it loads them into an array it's using too much memory. if you run `count($childIds)` after the `explode` method what do you get? Also, try logging `$i` (in the foreach loop) to a file, so that when you run out of memory you can see how many children you can load until you fail. You can likely paginate your collection of categories if you are loading to many at once.

Comment: It has 9 children. The categories are also not containing any products. Not likely to fill up more than 3GB RAM ;-) .Even when  I add `break;` after the first time `$children[] = $this->_categoryRepository->get($id);` it is throwing the exception.

Comment: I've run into something like this before and the problem was that I had to `load($id)` the entity from a model. When loading the entity, the other attributes came with it (like the description that you're after). In the scope of your first example, try: `$subCat->load($subCat->getData('entity_id'));` Does that load more meta data from the subscription for you?